# Adjust the size of an html element to another element

Tags: html, css, web

I recently stumbled upon a problem while coding html and css. I have this img element within a div and I want the div to resize to the size of my img. It's a responsive design, so whenever my img gets smaller, I want my div to resize with it.
Normally it would do this automatically, but since I used "position: absolute" in my img tag, the div height is simply 0.

Html: (note: there's 4 images because I'm creating a slideshow using css3, that's also why I need the position absolute on my img tag)

```
<div id="cf4a" class="shadow">
    <img src="Afbeeldingen/Home/img1.jpg">
    <img src="Afbeeldingen/Home/img2.jpg">
    <img src="Afbeeldingen/Home/img3.jpg">
    <img src="Afbeeldingen/Home/img4.jpg">
</div>
```

Css:

```
#cf4a {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 2.5%;
    width:95%;
    position: absolute;
}
#cf4a img {
    max-width: 1160px;
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1.25%;
}
```

How would I go and fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I edited my post with code

Comment: Why do you use `position: absolute` on your img tags? That is the root problem. Can you implement your design using a different technique?

Comment: How else would I overlap my images on top of each other for the slideshow I'm creating?

Answer (score 0):

this is a good tutorial for what you are trying to do,

basically you trick out the css by using a relative position but switching through what portion is viewed, using the overflow hidden property, check it out it is pretty cool!

http://csswizardry.com/2011/10/fully-fluid-responsive-css-carousel/

Comment: also I am new tot he website, if this works please mark it as right answer so I can get some points going and be able to comment on other peoples posts haha ;)